# Do ModelBuilder or Geoprocessing tasks run slower if screen locked?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, network, windows-7, geoprocessing-framework

Is it true if you are running ModelBuilder or a geoprocessing task on a large raster\vector dataset then locking the computer would that cause the ModelBuilder or any geoprocessing to run slower?

Is it the computer itself?  I am running a large raster datasets using ModelBuilder on a different computer machine and I unplugged the network to prevent from reboot or push in such as update patches.

I’d like to hear your comments or tips?

---

My work has these Insomina.exe and I'm wondering if this does made the difference to speed up the geoprocessing/model builder work ?

Here is the link: [Insomina.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/delay/give-your-computer-insomnia-free-tool-and-source-code-to-temporarily-prevent-a-machine-from-going-to-sleep)

Comment: Are you referring to locking Windows desktop via Ctrl+Alt+Delete --> Lock?

Comment: Radar, Correct !

Comment: Locking the desktop shouldn't have any effect on any processing taking place. You can test this by viewing your Task Manager performance when locked and unlocked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tested your hypothesis with a python script.  The attached script creates 500,000 points and buffers them to  5 units.  I ran two trials for three runs--one without locking and one with.  It appears that locking the desktop does indeed increase the processing time.

```py
# Import system modules
import arcpy, os, time, ctypes
from arcpy import env

env.overwriteOutput = True

# Create random points in an extent defined simply by numbers
outFolder = r"C:\Users\OWNER\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb"
numExtent = "0 0 10000 10000"
numPoints = 500000
outName = "myRandPnts"

start = time.clock()

# Create some random points and buffer them by 5 units
arcpy.CreateRandomPoints_management(outFolder, outName, "", numExtent, numPoints)
arcpy.Buffer_analysis (os.path.join(outFolder, outName), os.path.join(outFolder, "buffers"), 5)

end = time.clock()
final = end - start
print "Trial 1 (no desktop locking) took " + str(final) + " seconds"

# Lock the computer and run trial 2
user32 = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("user32.dll") 
user32.LockWorkStation()

start = time.clock()

# Create some random points and buffer them by 5 units
arcpy.CreateRandomPoints_management(outFolder, outName, "", numExtent, numPoints)
arcpy.Buffer_analysis (os.path.join(outFolder, outName), os.path.join(outFolder, "buffers"), 5)

end = time.clock()
final = end - start
print "Trial 2 (with desktop locking) took " + str(final) + " seconds"
```

[image]

Comment: Aaron, I don't know how to do this. Is this the python ? One other thing my office is Federal and don't know if this will work. I can try and see.

Comment: @PROBERT Yes, this is a python script that I used to test your hypothesis that running geoprocessing task with a locked computer is slower than the alternative.  Based on these results, that rumor appears to hold some truth.

Comment: Aaron, So I just have to copy and paste to pyhton script and make some changes to it. How does this work with the computer ?

Comment: @PROBERT I simply ran this script to test whether or not a system slows down geoprocessing when the computer is locked--mainly just to test your hypothesis.  If you want to test it yourself, make sure the      `outFolder = r"C:\Users\OWNER\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb"` is set to where you want the output data to go.  From there, copy and paste the script to your python window, press enter, sit back and wait.  It should produce results similar to the second window.  Keep in mind this script is only meant for test speed rather than refining your workflow--for that, simply turn off locking.

Comment: I got it, Aaron. Quite honestly I have to figure it out how to use Python. Thanks for your help. That is something I need to learn it though. Happy Holidays !